# DateFormat on Android: Unparseable date

Tags: java, android, date, date-format

I'm developing a function that extracts a date from a String and convert it to a Date. 
The date have the following format:

> dd-mmm-yyyy

where mmm is the month 3-digit name all lowercased.

The piece of code is the following:

```
if(queryLine.contains("Expiration Date:")){
String expString = queryLine.replace("Expiration Date:", "").trim();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
try {
    log.info("Exp: " + queryLine.replace("Expiration Date:", "").trim());
    expDate = df.parse(expString);
} catch (ParseException e) {                         
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If i try that code on a computer jvm it works fine and it converts the date without problem, but if i try to run it  on android i have the following error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "14-sep-2020"
     at org.whoislibrary.servers.WhoisCom.parseResponse(WhoisCom.java:39)
     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
     at org.whoislibrary.WhoisAbstract.executeQuery(WhoisAbstract.java:47)
     at org.whoislibrary.WhoisCommand.executeQuery(WhoisCommand.java:72)
     at org.HttpTest.HttpTestActivity.onCreate(HttpTestActivity.java:35)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea?

Comment: What locale are you using on Android?

Comment: What happens if you don't lowercase the month? i.e. Do you still get an NPE with `14-Sep-2020` as the input?

Comment: I tried expDate = df.parse("14-Sep-2020"); and i still receive the NPE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure (I will check in a moment) but I think the problem is that for MMM your month must be in proper locale too. So Sep on your PC (presumably locale set to EN) would need to be expressed in Italian if you use Italian locale on Android. 
Could you try it?

Comment: O_O you are right. That was the problem!!! I didn't think about that. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the code works fine on your computer I would suspect unprintable characters in your input string which cause parse problem on Android. Can you try the following which removes control characters from the parsed string.

```
expDate = df.parse(expString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", ""));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now I receive a NullPointerException on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying an English locale when you create the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```